# Linux C server standart socket reading problem with browser interaction

Tags: c, linux, sockets, server

Good afternoon, stackoverflow.

I tried to make a simple server according to the standard scheme: one port is listened to (listen), then (accept), then a separate process through a socket with an ID received through (accept) reads the request and issues a response to it.

When I did one read (recv) everything worked well.
But I decided to provide for a large request length and at the same time do the parsing. For this I made a function (getsym).
And there was a problem, for some reason, after reading the last part (the length of which is <buffer length), when another one is called (read / recv), everything hangs.

What I did to resolve this:
0) I put debug outputs everywhere, thanks to which I realized that everything hangs after reading the last part of the request.

1. There was an obvious solution - if the length of the last part is <the length of the buffer, no longer read from the socket. But the question arises - what if the request length is a multiple of the buffer length?
2. I tried to make the socket non-blocking, then an error occurs immediately - length = -1 (error). Apparently this needs to be processed, but I did not do this because I do not know how to determine the end of the request.
3. I checked to see if the descriptors were not closed, but everything is closed.

Total where I suspect the problem is:
-I suspect the problem is in the read call

I will be SO VERY grateful if someone tells me what to do. +1000 for your karma.

PS Thats the function that reads the request in a separate process

```
void getsym_sub (int sockfd)
  {
  static char local_buf [HTTP_BUF_SIZE + 1] = {}; // Äëÿ áóôåðèçàöèè
  static int position = -1; // Ïîçèöèÿ -1 çíà÷èò åùå íè÷åãî íå ÷èòàëè
  static int length = 0;

  position++;
  if (position == length)
    {
      printf ("\n attempt \n");
      length = read (sockfd, &local_buf, HTTP_BUF_SIZE);
      printf ("\n %d \n", length);
      if (length < 0)
        {
        printf ("\n error occured \n");
        SYM = 0;
        return;
        }
      if (length == 0)
        {
        printf ("\n  endof occured \n");
        SYM = 0;
        return;
        }
      local_buf [length] = 0;
    }

  SYM = local_buf [position];
  return;
  }
```

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: ` {
  <declarations>

  position++;
  if (position == length)
    {
      printf ("\n attempt \n");
      length = read (sockfd, &local_buf, HTTP_BUF_SIZE);
      printf ("\n %d \n", length);
      if (length < 0)
        {
        printf ("\n error occured \n");
        SYM = 0;
        return;
        }
      if (length == 0)
        {
        printf ("\n  endof occured \n");
        SYM = 0;
        return;
        }
      local_buf [length] = 0;
    }

  SYM = local_buf [position];
  return;
  } `

And it hangs between printf 'attempt' and printf '%d', length

Comment: Code should be in your *question*, not in comments. Please [edit] your question to include your code.

Comment: It seems that I forgot to mention that it hangs between
```printf ("\n attempt \n");``` and ``` printf ("\n %d \n", length);```

Comment: TCP: Unless you have a protocol that defines a message unit, it is not possible to reliably transfer anything longer than one byte. 'what if the request length is a multiple of the buffer length?' you need to read multiple times, in a loop, until your protocol indicates that a complete message unit has been received.

Comment: Ehm, sorry, forgot to mention I used TCP protocol, @martin-james

The problem is that it is not clear for me, hpw to understand that it is the end. 
For example if we use not-blocking sockets, we have ```read``` returning ```-1``` and ```errno = EAGAIN``` but it does not tell us that is the end, does it? May be it is just the end of the data in system buffer, but not the end of the request?

So how to understand that s the end if I use http over tcp? To use info from Content-length, right?

Comment: @AYAWARRIOR depends on the HTTP version. Read the specs.

Comment: I assume this is a toy / school project (no serious project uses a process-per-connection design)... if so, I recommend that you review the task materials as well as the message protocol specification (HTTP?) to see how a message length / boundary is detected. Also, **`position` only grows**, you need to test that it doesn't **overflow the buffer**.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to know how many bytes you have to receive because the code looks like it will work if the client closes the connection.

If you know how many bytes are to follow, you can adjust the number of bytes to read so that you never try to read more than the client will send. So pass the length as the minimum of the number of bytes not received yet and the actual buffer size.